# Can some offer some assistance with a Power BI Embedded issue in my website

Tags: c#, asp.net, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm struggling to use Power BI Embedded to render a report on my webpage.

I am working on a proof of concept and have a company Office 365 account with a Power BI Pro trial. We also have an azure account that our local Active Directory is replicated to. I have access to my Power BI account in my office 365 and can make changes there, but I do not have access to the Azure AD account and have to ask for changes to be made here for me.

I have been into my Power BI account and created a report, and have published this to a shared workspace. We have also registered an app (our website) in Azure that points to the website URL

When I look at the App in Azure I can see an Application (Client) ID, a Directory (Tenant) ID and an Object ID.
The "Application ID URI" begins "api://" and continues with the Application (Client) ID value.

Following the videos hosted at Channel 9 ([Power Bi Embedded - Setting up and Getting Started](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html)) it all looked very easy, and following the guys code made perfect sense. However, as soon as I ran the code I'd copied I got an error when making the call to AcquireTokenAsync (with the Reourse parameter value of "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", the Application (Client) ID, and my Azure AD credentials)

The error reads :

> "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
>   Trace ID: d0bdb825-de11-43a0-8171-f5ef2e25dd00
>   Correlation ID: 6dc1555b-b42b-46ea-93e5-9b1fa4c7fedd
>   Timestamp: 2020-01-14 13:04:24Z"

There's no mention of "client_assertion" anywhere, but even though I do have a client_secret (I can see this in the registration for the App in Azure), it's not clear to me where this would be set, or if it's a red herring and I simply don't have the App registered or configured correctly.

I'm hoping someone else knows why I'm seeing this and can suggest a way to fix it, and suspect its more to do with config (either in Power BI or the Azure App).

My method is shown below

```
protected async void GetToken()
    {
        try
        {
            //  Config.AuthorityUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/"
            //  Config.ResourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
            //  Config.ApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/"
            //  These will be changed to use a service account later...
            //  Globals.DomainUsername = my AD account username
            //  Globals.DomainPassword = my AD account password
            //  Config.ClientID = Application (Client) ID in Azure app
            //  Config.GroupID = the Group ID taken from Power BI and matches the Application (Client) ID
            //  ReportID = the report ID taken from the Querystring when viewing report in Power BI

            var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(Globals.DomainUsername, Globals.DomainPassword);
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(Config.AuthorityUrl);
            var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Config.ResourceUrl, Config.ClientID, credentials);

            if (authenticationResult == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not get authenticationResult");
            }

            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

            using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(Config.ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
            {
                var report = await client.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(Config.GroupID, ReportID);

                if (report == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not get report");
                }

                var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");
                var token = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(Config.GroupID, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

                if (token == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not get token");
                }

                // global scope variables...
                reportURL = report.EmbedUrl;
                rID = report.Id;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of the application that you registered - web or native? Did you tried to set `allowPublicClient` in app's manifest to `true`?

Comment: I've just set the allowPublicClient to true in the manifest, but I'm not sure how/where to check the application type.

Comment: Andrey, this is a web type application (found under the "Authentication" menu option under "Manage"). The URL points to the page where the AquireTokenAsync method is called.

Comment: Try to register native app (yes, even for web apps there are cases when you must use native).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register the app as the native app.
Change *AuthorityUri* to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/

According to new changes in the UI for Azure App registration, you will need to enable the additional setting called Default Client Type to Yes.

[image]

For better understanding, please look here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-devicecodeflow-v2/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that I see that is that the Authority URL is different.

I would try and change the AuthorityUrl to https://login.windows.net/common/
or https://login.windows.net/{Your Tenant, eg contoso.onmicrosoft.com}/

Also I would double check that you have added the correct Power BI API permissions to the app registration in Azure. I didn't have any client secret generated until we started switching to Service Principal.